# Unable to login to Rundeck with default credentials

Tags: amazon-ecs, rundeck

I am trying to login to Rundeck community (4.5.0) that I installed on a AWS ECS cluster behind an Application Load Balancer. The health checks on target groups are good/healthy and I can reach the landing page of Rundeck too.

Once I enter default admin credentials, the page keeps loading for more an hour and times out eventually. There are no error logs in Cloudwatch as well. Same image works locally but not on AWS setup.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to solve this is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED=true` env var in your deployment. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/configuration/docker.html#basic).

Comment: I did that and it's giving me a 504 Gateway Timeout. I even added RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL to point to the DNS name of ALB. Still no luck.

Comment: I had to remove `RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED=true` and add `RUNDECK_GRAILS_URL`. Now I have the landing page and the login works with default credentials.

Comment: Wow! Weird! Glad to know!

Comment: Similarly, if I want to configure Rundeck to use a PostGres DB, should I specify `RUNDECK_DATABASE_URL` to point to the RDS PG DB I create?

Comment: Yes, please take a look at this Rundeck + PGSQL example: https://github.com/rundeck/docker-zoo/blob/master/postgres/docker-compose.yml You can see all DB related env vars.

Comment: I had to update the ALB to internal LB. I can reach the URL but after providing default credentials, there is no further action, the page keeps loading. I have added RUNDECK_SERVER_FORWARDED = true to the ECS task definition but no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, the default URL is accessible only at https://<rundeck_addr>/user/login. I would like to remove `/user/login` from the URL that users will access. How should I go about that?

Comment: All good here. Seems like the internal ALB is affecting the ability to pull docker image from DockerHub. Using ECR for now until I figure out a better solution.

You can mark this issue as Closed.